# Where to Find a Matrix Representation of the Monster Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, computer-algebra-systems

On the site for the Atlas of Finite Simple Groups, Robert Wilson posts that the Monster group has a computer representation over GF(2) which is calculable only with special programs (I assume he means GAP, Sage, etc.).  However, I haven't seen any links for the actual 196882 order matrix representation anywhere.  Does anyone know where one might find this data?

Comment: I don't think he means GAP, Sage, etc, he means programs that have been written specifically to compute with this representation. So there would be no point in making the data available without the programs.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case.  I assume such programs aren't publicly available?

Comment: I don't think they are publicly available. You would need to write to the author and ask.

Comment: Did you manage to find the explicit matrices? I'm also looking for them...

Comment: No, sorry. I emailed Robert Wilson and he essentially said he's working on a program to do these kinds of calculations and said nothing else.  It's his discovery, I get it. But it's still a shame.

Comment: See  [The mmgroup API reference](https://mmgroup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for a publicly avaliable representation of the monster modulo small odd primes.